# Angular module declaration

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add 'base64' module to my Angular page controller.
Until now I have declared my controller like this:

```
angular.module('app').controller('newProjectController', newProjectController);
```

now what I should be doing looking at the git (https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64) is

```
angular.module('app', ['base64'] ).controller('newProjectController', newProjectController);
```

However, what happens is that my view is just empty. It does not give any error message, but the view is rendered empty. I have included the js file in my index.html page, before using the controller.
The same problem persists when I use

```
angular.module('app', [] ).controller('newProjectController', newProjectController);
```

so the 'base64' module cannot be the problem in this...
Any ideas of what's going wrong? I am on Angular version 1.4.1.

Comment: Do you have somewhere else in your code where you declare `angular.module('app', [...])`…? You ought to be, because `.module('app')` by itself refers to a module which is already declared elsewhere…

Comment: Everywhere else I am using `angular.module('app')`. I don't really know what you mean?

Comment: I'm saying you must initially declare your module using the form `.module(name, […])` somewhere (*two* arguments, not just the name).

Comment: If I do that in my "MainController" I still have the same problem

Comment: "It does not give any error message": do you mean in the Developer Tools Console? If yes, are you sure? And, without adding any module, does your view "works", i.e. display something?

Comment: I've found the problem. I need to declare it in app.js where i also declare the ngRoute. Otherwise it's overwriting the routing and that's why I just get that blank screen

Comment: Yeah, again, because `.module(name, […])` *declares a new module,* overwriting *everything*.

Answer (score 0):

first define module

```
angular.module('app',['base64'])
```

second define controller by referencing to defined module

```
angular.module('app' ).controller('newProjectController', newProjectController)
```

third make good tea ))